# Find a string and replace the entire line for that string

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to update the value of a specifc key (say, `key2`) in the `yaml` file using shell command. I am trying to use `sed` but it is working only if I have a specific value, for example, `TBD` in this case. But I want to update the value everytime irrespective of any value. Also my replacement string is stored in a variable. Can anybody suggest me what command shall I use?

```
hash.yaml file

---
key1: val1
key2: <TBD>
key3:
 - val3_1
 - val3_2
```

This is what I tried and works for me. But only if I have "TBD" as my search key.

```
sed -i "s;<TBD>;$var;g" hash.yaml
```

Comment: Sed is not the right tool to parse YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` to replace any value of the key `key2` with the new value stored in a variable called `$var`:

```
var='foobar'

sed -E "s~^([ \t]*key2:[ \t]*).*~\1$var~" hash.yml

key1: val1
key2: foobar
key3:
 - val3_1
 - val3_2
```

In the expression `^([ \t]*key2:[ \t]*).*` we match `key2:` at line start with optional whitespace before and after it. `.*` in the end will match anything for `key2`.

If you want to edit file in-place then use `-i` flag for `sed`:

```
sed -i '' -E "s~^([ \t]*key2:[ \t]*).*~\1$val~" hash.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a proper YAML parser in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (the right tool for the right job...) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Config::YAML;
use YAML::XS qw/DumpFile/;

my $ds = Config::YAML->new(
    config => "hash.yaml"
);

$ds->{key2} = 'FOOBAR';

DumpFile("./new.yaml", $ds);
```

then,

```
cat new.yaml
```